# Autocomplete search with AngularJS and php TypeError Cannot read property 'searchText' of undefined

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to make autocomplete search, so I want to get data from a php file but I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchText' of undefined.

I don't figure out what is the problem, I tried for 2 days.

Here is my code:

**clientToServer.js**

```
function CltToServer($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "PureAngualr/SearchResultsQuery.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {searchText: $rootScope.searchText},
        async: false,

        params: {
            action: "get"
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $rootScope.suggestions = response.data;
        alert(2);

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
}
```

**autocomplete.js**

```
app1.controller('autoCompleteCTRL', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

    //Sort Array
    /*$rootScope.searchItems.sort();*/
    //Define Suggestions List
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $scope.selectedItem = undefined;
    $rootScope.suggestions = undefined;
    //Define Selected Suggestion Item
    $rootScope.selectedIndex = -1;


    //Function To Call On ng-change
    $rootScope.search = function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

        $rootScope.searchItems = CltToServer($scope, $rootScope, $http);

        alert(1);
        $rootScope.suggestions = CltToServer($scope, $rootScope, $http);
        var myMaxSuggestionListLength = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.searchItems.length; i++) {
            var searchItemsSmallLetters = angular.lowercase($rootScope.searchItems[i]);
            var searchTextSmallLetters = angular.lowercase($scope.searchText);
            if (searchItemsSmallLetters.indexOf(searchTextSmallLetters) !== -1) {
                $rootScope.suggestions.push(searchItemsSmallLetters);
                myMaxSuggestionListLength += 1;
                if (myMaxSuggestionListLength == 5) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="autoCompleteCTRL">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for items" id="textFiled" class="input" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" ng-keyup="checkKeyUp($event)" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()"/>
    <ul class="suggestions-list ">
        <li ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions track by $index" ng-class="{active : selectedIndex === $index}" ng-click="AssignValueAndHide($index)">
            {{suggestion}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your searchText is defined in $scope or $rootScope?

Comment: May be wrong but `url: "PureAngualr/SearchResultsQuery.php"` looks like a typo to me. Is it not `PureAngular`?

Comment: PureAngualr is just a field where I put the php file

Comment: Finaly I find the problem, I must add controller to clientToServer.js because I use two separates js file. But nothing happend, the suggestions list doesn't appear!! Do you know why? There is somthing wrong with my function in autocomplete.js?